# How much magic is allowed in the streets of Absalom?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion

In a campaign set in Absalom, what magic is allowed? The Absalom Guide specifically calls out Invisibility and Confusion; the magic police, the Varlokkur, track down magicians that cast them.

Does that mean a 5th level wizard can just cast as he wants in the streets of Absalom? Is it the same in other countries?

Comment: I've eliminated the chattiness, making it a bit more applicable to others, and cleaned up the grammar a bit. Feel free to roll it back or make further edits if I've removed something you think is vitally important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Absalom, the Varlokkur investigate any crimes conducted using magic.  Some spells are illegal per se, which is invisibility and anything that conceals you (misdirection, etc.). Others are treated as weapons, like charm person - they can be used in self defense but not used at will in general.  All spells not specifically listed as illegal at a Spell Fete are legal, but keep in mind that cops can find a crime to fit what you're doing if you're being annoying. A fifth level wizard can "cast as they will" - but if they break something it's vandalism, if they threaten someone or cause a panic it's assault. Just like here in Texas you can open carry a weapon, but the second you point it at someone or brandish it threateningly you get go have a nap.

Is it the same in other countries? No of course not, the hundreds of other countries and cities and cultures have differing approaches to magic.  It's too broad to cover them all here.